# .deb package for Ubuntu: correct Java dependency

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java, deb

I'm currently in the progress of creating a `.deb` package of our Java-based application, especially for Ubuntu users. Our application runs with the JRE 1.6 and 1.7 from OpenJDK (`openjdk-6-jre-headless` and `openjdk-7-jre-headless`), but the use of JRE 1.7 is preferred. Because of that, I'm using

```
Recommends: openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

but I'm unsure whether this is the correct dependency. When installing our bundle and neither `openjdk-6-jre-headless` nor `openjdk-7-jre-headless` is installed, it should install `openjdk-7-jre-headless`.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your old question... You should depend upon `default-jre-headless (>= 1.6)` (which is filled by `openjdk-7-jre-headless` by default, but allows any 1.6 or newer JRE that the user has installed to work). You don't need to recommend anything, as the user will get the recommended JRE if they don't have one installed, otherwise, they already have a JRE installed and you should use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should depend upon `java-runtime-headless (>= 1.6)` (which is filled by `openjdk-7-jre-headless`, and allows any 1.6 or newer JRE that the user has installed to work).

This allows for much more flexibility. For example, I run `oracle-java8-jdk` on my system; this provides `default-jre-headless 1.8` (as well as `java7-runtime-headless`, `java6-runtime-headless`, and `java5-runtime-headless`), but any dependencies upon `openjdk` would most likely result in me not installing your program because I have no desire to install an older JRE.

Comment: I have installed `openjdk-7-jre-headless` on my machine and my application works. When I try to run `sudo apt-get install default-jre-headless` it wants to download further ~35 MB and install that. I want to avoid this additional bloat if it's not necessary.

Comment: @ThomasS. Whoops. Seems `java-runtime-headless` is the correct virtual package to put as a dependency, with `openjdk-7-jre-headless` as recommended. I don't have any direct experience with this, so please continue to comment on what you figure out.